# Kivy android path of SDCard does not work

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to save user input into a file that I can later use on my computer. I can't use relative path because I do not have root on my phone so no access to it. I'm trying to use `android.storage` module and `primary_external_storage_path` but it simply doesn't work on my phone. Here's just a fragment of my app.

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                     Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
SD_CARD = primary_external_storage_path()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        with open('settings.txt', 'r') as file:
            f = open(SD_CARD + today.strftime("%Y_%m_%d") + ".txt", 'a+')

   ...
```

Where seems to be the problem? I'm using Android 7.1.1 on my phone. As far as I know buildozer (which i use to build APK) contains android package so everything should be included. Something in `.spec` file of buildozer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to include `android` in your requirements of `buildozer.spec` file. Even after that if you are getting error then you might be using older version of kivy. So you have to use the latest version by specifying your requirements as `kivy==2.0.0`. You have to rebuild your app after changing the kivy version. Or there's another method by which you can get external storage path. You can use `os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE')`. This will give you the path of external storage

Comment: I did cut some of the app to only show path and it's content. When using `os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE')` it shows `\storage` but when trying to print `os.listdir(path)` the app doesn't even start again...

Comment: do you have permission to read external storage? and which kivy version have you specified in your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for permissions before the whole thing. I'm using newest kivy.

Comment: can you share logs you got from [logcat](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform)?

Comment: Looks like nothing appears in logcat, I've only noticed logs about turning phone on.

Comment: See it should work fine until unless there's a problem with your buildozer.spec file. It might because of missing requirement or using an older version of kivy in buildozer. Are you sure both of these are correct? Can you share your buildozer.spec file? and is everything correct in your .py file?

Comment: I don't know why I thought that there's 2.0.0 kivy version in spec file, it was 1.9.x...Thanks for help.